# count and repetive structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have 490 students
We have a capacity of 20 students per classroom
Ie we have 490/20 = 24.5 ie 25 sections
First I want to arrange students in alphabetical order
Secondly I want to make a table containing
Id_classroom and id_student attributes
My Problem is in id_classroom and how to populate it
How can I automatically give this
Students from 1 to 20 === id_classroom = 1
Students from 21 to 40 === id_classroom = 2
and so on

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SQL RESQUEST, the function FLOOR is your friend.
What it does is reduce your number to the largest integer less than or equal to the expression.

Let's say you have a student id 46.
The operation would look like this:

```
46-1= 45     //index starts at 1 instead of 0.
45/20=2.25   
Floor(2.25)=2   
2+1=3
```

So your SQL would have something as such in it:

```
id_classroom=FLOOR((id_student-1)/20)+1
```

Comment: Since student id's appear to be one-based, it would be `Floor( ( id_student - 1 ) / 20 ) + 1`.

Comment: Please , why you add -1 ?

Comment: The -1 is there because (20/20)+1=2. Now if the ids of your students start at 1 as you said, you want the 20th  student to be part of the first group. ((20-1)/20)+1=1.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, I just thought something up :)
EDIT: Just noticed this was in SQL not C# forum. Not sure if still useful.

```
TotalStudents = 490;
MaxCap = 20;
RoomID = 0;
Dictionary<RoomID, MaxCap>() StudentsAndRooms = new Dictionary();

void PopulateRoom(Dictionary<int,int> myD)
{
myD = StudentsAndRooms;

for(int i = 0; i < TotalStudents; i++)
{
if(myD[RoomID].Value.Count <= MaxCap)
{
myD[RoomID] = myD[RoomID +1]
Debug.Log("Added Room");
}
else if(myD[RoomID].Value.Count != MaxCap)
{
myD[RoomID] +=1;
Debug.Log("Added Student");
}
else
{
Debug.Log("Something went wrong!");
}
}


void Start()
{
PopulateRoom(StudentsAndRooms);
}
```